# Scala-Chart histrogram with multiple bars per bin

Tags: scala, charts, jfreechart

I need to create a Histogram in Scala and I need to create two series in one chart which is distrubuted into 5 bins. I've found a library [scala-chart](https://github.com/wookietreiber/scala-chart) which is a wrapper around [jFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/).
I can create a histrogram dataset add two series and make a chart just fine as so:

```
  val data:HistogramDataset = new HistogramDataset
  data.addSeries("Class 0",class0,5)
  data.addSeries("Class 1",class1,5)

  val chart = ChartFactories.XYBarChart(class1data)
```

However the two bars simply overlap so I can't see much information. There is a jFreeChart class that seems to be able to do the job: [ClusteredXYBarRenderer](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/ClusteredXYBarRenderer.html), but how do I use this to draw my chart?

---

As a bonus question, is there anyway to make it show the different distributions in percent instead of simply showing them as a number of how many values there are in each bin?

Ideally I'm looking for a final product like this: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you look [at this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartBarChartDemo.htm). It uses the `DefaultCategoryDataset`, where categories = bins. You could use scala-chart's `toCategoryDataset` for a `Tuple3` with `(count, series, bin)`. But it is a little complicated to order the data correctly. I have found that in many cases it is indeed easier to construct the datasets using the default Java API instead of the `to...` methods of scala-chart.

```
import scalax.chart._

val ds = new org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset
ds.addValue(5, "Class A", "Bin 1")
ds.addValue(7, "Class A", "Bin 2")
ds.addValue(8, "Class B", "Bin 1")
ds.addValue(3, "Class B", "Bin 2")

val chart = ChartFactories.BarChart(ds)
chart.show()
```

[image]

To use percentages, the simplest is to provide the values already translated into percent. Otherwise you would need to change the axis tick label renderer.

Comment: Thanks. I'm quite keen on using the automatic bin-distribution function which is provided with the HistrogramDataset object, as I understanding it using the above I would have to bistrubute the values myself right?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Have you tried to use `HistogramDataset` with `BarChart` (instead of `XYBarChart`)?

Comment: right okay, I would really rather avoid having to sort the date myself. I can't use the HistrgramDataset with BarChart as BarChart requires an CategoryDataset which the HistrogramDataset is not I'm afraid. Think I might just go for making another graph instead of having it in two. How would I go about changing the values on the axis (in my original code).

Comment: Sum the counts in your dataset first, then divide each datum by this count = in percent (multiple by 100 possibly). Or `plot.getRangeAxis.asInstanceOf[NumberAxis].setTickUnit(...)` to use custom formatting (override the `valueToString` method).

Comment: I don't think dividing works. I am not suppling the count of each bin manually to the Histrogram Dataset, I am simply supplying an array of doubles and the HistrogramDatasets automatically figures out what the bin ranges should be and where to put each value and then sums that up.

Comment: Actually I ended up using HistrogramDataset to deal with the sorting and then use the get methods to get the count of each bin. A bit messy but works. Thanks